# Issue with control chars - PHP does not print \t (tab character)

Tags: php, excel

i'm sending an XLS file with the header. Everything is working fine. But when i tell it to print the tab to separate the cells in the XLS by print `\t`. It does not prints the tab. It just prints the '\t' in the file and when i download the XLS file everything that should be in different cell is all in one cell with text like:

```
val1\tval2\tval3\t
```

Those three values should be separate in their separate cells.
i have been trying for 2 hours now nothing is working :(.

i send headers like this:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.$fileextention);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

and just print the values like

```
echo $val1 . '\t' . $val2 . '\t' . $val3;
```

i have tried using single or double quts. and print and echo both buy still :(

Comment: Show the code you are using to generate the XLS file

Comment: Please show a code example. Are you using single or double quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (see quotes)

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
echo "val1\tval2\tval3";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that quotes cause the issue.

```
echo $val1 . "\t" . $val2 . "\t" . $val3;
```

should do the thing. Just look at this:

```
<?php

echo 'Test\tTest';
echo "\r\n";
echo "Test\tTest";
echo "\r\n";
```

which outputs:

```
Test\tTest
Test    Test
```

Use double quotes when you need control chars. 
Hopefully this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes: "\t". Within single quotes only `\\` and `\'` is recognised.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo $val1 . "\t" . $val2 . "\t" . $val3;
```

If it doesn't, it's a bug in PHP.